# How to reate two different headers for desktop and mobile using xml?

Tags: magento2.3, xml, header

I want to create two headers one for `desktop` and other for `mobile`.

How can I achieve this, do i need to edit `default.xml` or need to add some conditions to meet the requirements ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to detect mobile via xml layout, you have to create your two header, then you display it just for mobile via css `media queries`

A quick example :

```
<div class="header-desktop">...</div>
<div class="header-mobile">...</div>
```

css:

```
.header-mobile {
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .header-mobile {
         display:block !important;
    }

    .header-desktop {
         display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally we use CSS to achieve responsive website ("different layout" in mobile and desktop).

So what you can do is add the components to the place you need both in mobile as well as desktop. Then give them different class like:

desktop(display:none; when screen < 800px)

mobile(display:none; when screen > 801px)

So in the layout, it may looks like:

```
 <referenceContainer name="head.block">
    <container name="navigation.wrapper" htmlClass="mobile">
       <block name="navigation" class="../../../../../../" template="../../../" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="body.top">
    <container name="navigation.second.wrapper" htmlClass="desktop">
     <block name="navigation.second" class="../../../../../../" template="../../../" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Then you have two navigation in the layout but only one will display in desktop screen size, and the other will display in mobile screen. or you can do by select different theme for both layout.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i want to create two headers which includes logo search minicart etc, how can i achieve that?

Comment: in above code you can mentioned your template file then call this.